# Build Raster Attribute Table with GDAL Utilities

Tags: raster, gdal, attribute-table

Is there a way to build a raster attribute table using one of the GDAL utilities?  I know you can view it using `gdalinfo` and I have successfully created one using Python, but it would be so much easier to just run a command line utility to build a raster attribute table on a raster.

Comment: what format do you want the output table to be in?

Comment: Well, in Python there is a RasterAttributeTableClass that you can use to build the raster attribute table directly into the raster.  It may be stored in the aux file, I'm not sure.  But ArcGIS recognizes it and will symbolize by it.  You can also view it in ArcGIS just as you would any other attribute table.

Comment: So you're trying to get it into ArcGIS?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I do have access to ArcGIS that I use for viewing rasters occasionally.  I realize that using ArcGIS to create the raster attribute table is an option, but I have several GDAL workflows (using 64bit GDAL) and I want the RAT to be part of that workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the documentation

http://gdal.org/classGDALRasterAttributeTable.html

They are known as RATs and came about after your question.
http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2005-July/006082.html

I believe ArcGIS will not read them but would like to be corrected.

Comment: FWIW, the page is nowadays here: https://gdal.org/doxygen/classGDALRasterAttributeTable.html