# Rasterizing vector layer with PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, rasterization, postgis-raster, 3d-model

I have a vector layer with 2498 features (houses) that I want to rasterize/produce a raster image from but can't figure out how:

> Column MARK_Z = is Meters above see-level for the base of each house
>
> Column Z = Total meters above see-level for each house
>
> Column BYGG_H = is each buildings total height from base

So ideally I would want code two of them into the new raster attribute, but *Raster > Conversion > Rasterize (Vector to Raster)* only let's me chose one, so I'm looking at different ways to solve this.

I have a PostGIS up and running with Qgis, **How can I rasterize this with PostGIS through Qgis?**

More information:

Download this exact vector layer and see if you can sort it out?
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwFHJFrNX33hZ2E0UlEtZDlUOXc

Running QGIS 2.18.0 'Las Palmas' but could change if another version works better?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Or is this still impossible in QGIS? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28199/is-it-possible-to-perform-3d-vector-editing-in-qgis

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a lot of the same problems you have with this dataset (both this question and your others), and struggled to get this into postgres.

**Importing into postgres**

Your geometries are of type 31 - **shp2pgsql** doesn't like that (it's expecting 1006). So create a new shapefile from the old with ogr2ogr, and tell it to save as MULTIPOLYGONZ

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" fixed.shp ./Byggnad_area_3D.shp -nlt MULTIPOLYGONZ
```

That gets us to the next problem :)

You may need to change the [postgres database encoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html). I tried several (UTF-8, LATIN1, LATIN4) without success... I get encoding errors. Used this to set the database encoding (I called mine 'sweden')

```
update pg_database set encoding = pg_char_to_encoding('LATIN1') where datname = 'sweden'
```

**Limitations of gdal_rasterize**

A further problem is that **gdal_rasterize** doesn't support burn values for polygon z coordinates ([source](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html)). There's a **-3d** option but according to the docs...

> Indicates that a burn value should be extracted from the "Z" values of the feature. 
>   **As of now, only points and lines are drawn in 3D**.

I was able to convert the fixed.shp to lines, and rasterize that. But I suspect that's not quite the effect you were after.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a [raster attribute table](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterAttributeTable.html) to me.
According to this stackexchange post ([Build Raster Attribute Table with GDAL Utilities](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48264/build-raster-attribute-table-with-gdal-utilities)) you can create them using GDAL, but according to another post ([Accessing raster attribute table in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32803/accessing-raster-attribute-table-in-qgis?rq=1)) they are not yet compatible with QGIS.

Give PostGIS or ArcGIS a try instead.

Comment: Thanks! So strange that this isn't possible yet!? I will edit the question to make it PostGIS specific since I have a PostGIS installation up and running with Qgis.

Comment: If someones got spare time I would appreciate input releated to this question. The main problem I'm trying to solve can be found here: could you think of a work-around? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218840/how-is-this-elevation-mcda-possible-in-qgis